How can I automatically add rows in an excel sheet from a different file
I have an excel sheet and two csv files with the data from our system export. While it is easy to use an excel formula and import the values from the csv files into the excel sheet, it all breaks down, when the csv files are updated - which they are regularly.
I want to automatically want to check if a) the csv files have a new entry (based on ID) and if yes add the entry to the excel file.
Is this doable with excel Makros or do I need a python script for that?

I would say welcome to the board, but you've been here 5 years already.... so [ask] and [mcve].  Also have a look at Power Query to import and refresh data.
